# Map the area to the left and below $xy=1\quad (x,y>0)$ to the UHP

Tags: complex-analysis, conformal-geometry

> The region to the left and below the hyperbola $xy=1$ is to be mapped
>   conformally and one-to-one onto the upper the half-plane. (See picture below.)

**Ideas:** The only thing I've seen before in terms of conformal maps and hyperbolae is that the area to the right of the hyperbola $x^2-y^2=1$ is mapped to $\text{Re}(z)>1$ by the map $z\mapsto z^2$. Here we have zero in the region, so the squaring map is not conformal there.

Any ideas?

**Update:** There is a nearly identical problem in Ahlfors, exercise 3.4.2 #8, as @bryanj points out. The problem there reads

> Map the part of the $z$-pland to the left of the right-hand branch of
>   the hyperbola $x^2-y^2=1$ on a half plane. **Hint:** Consider on one
>   side the mapping of the upper half of the region by $w=z^2$, on the
>   other side the mapping of a quadrant by $w=z^3-3z.$

I don't quite understand the hint. Perhaps @bryanj can clarify, since he appears to be following it.

I believe I understand Ahlfors' description of the map $z\mapsto z^3-3z$...he parameterizes regions in the $z$- and $w$-planes by a parameter $\zeta$ s.t. $z=\zeta + \frac1\zeta$ and $w=\zeta^3 + \frac{1}{\zeta^3}$.

[image]

Comment: Since when is $x$ equal to the imaginary part, and $y$ to real?

Comment: When the region has a line of symmetry, consider dividing it along this line. If you can map one half to UHP, then by the reflection principle the whole region is mapped to the plane with a slit, and that can be mapped to UHP... Here the line of symmetry is $x=y$. Let's take the part to the left of this line, where $x<y$. The squaring map $w=  z^2$ is conformal here. It sends the half-domain to  $3/4$ of a plane with the corner $2i$, slit along  the line segment  $[0,2i]$. Unfortunately, I get stuck here...

Comment: @PostNoBulls Good question there...this is a diagram from an old qualifier...I swear I think they put stuff like that in just to mess with us. They are full of careless mistakes

Comment: @PostNoBulls A plane with a slit can be mapped to the upper half-plane conformally even though one is simply connected and the other is not?

Comment: If the slit is half-infinite, there is no problem. If it's finite, then $\infty$ is considered a point in the domain. Then you map the endpoints of the slit to $0,\infty$ etc.. Think in terms of the Riemann sphere: first you map half-domain to the Northern hemisphere, then erase a contiguous part of the equator. It does not really matter which part you erase.

Comment: Given the weird transposition of real and imaginary parts, is it reasonable to guess that the examiners also mixed up the domain and its complement? Then the question would become very easy, of course.

Comment: @PostNoBulls I wish I could assume that...since they specifically said "to the left and below" it doesn't seem like a careless mistake in the drawing. But I certainly allow that there could be an error in the design of the question.

Comment: This is a problem from Ahlfors: 3.4.2 #8 (except he's looking at the plane to the left of $x^2 - y^2 = 1$). He gives the hint: try looking at using $z^2$, but also look at how $w = z^3-3z$ affects a quadrant. Try squaring, then applying $2(z-1)$, then using the inverse of $w = z^3-3z$. It looks like even thought $z^2$ is not conformal at $0$, the composite still is.

Comment: @bryanj But surely the derivative of the composite map is zero at $z=0$, making it not conformal, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Halving a symmetric region**

When the region to be mapped has a line of symmetry $L$, consider dividing it along this line. If you   map one half of the region to a quadrant so that $L$ goes to one of two sides, then reflection across $L$ produces a conformal map of the entire region onto half-plane.

In this example, the line of symmetry is $x=y$. Let's take the part to the right of this line, where $x>y$. The squaring map $w=z^2$ is conformal here. The half-hyperbola goes to the half-line $\operatorname{Im}w=2$,
$\operatorname{Re}w\ge 0$. The line $L$ gets wrapped around at point $0$, and ends up being a half-line, going from  $(1+i)^2 = 2i$ to $0^2=0$ then back up along the imaginary axis.

Thus, the  image of half-region is bounded by  he
vertical half-line $[0,i\infty)$ and the horizontal half-line $[2i,2i+\infty)$. How to map this ugly thing $\Omega$ to a quadrant?

**Weird trick**

It turns out to be easier to do the opposite: map the positive quadrant to this ugly thing. Specifically, the map $\Phi(z) = z^3-3z$ does the following:

[image: lol]

Indeed, $iy \mapsto -i(y+y^3)$, so the upper imaginary half-axis goes to the bottom imaginary half-axis in a monotone way. Along the real axis, $\Phi$  sends $0$ to $0$, then goes to the left
until $\Phi(1)=-2$ ($1$ is its critical point), the goes to the right into $+\infty$.

The fact that $\Phi$ is injective in the open quadrant can be inferred from the boundary correspondence. A quarter-arc $|z|=R$, with $R$ large, is mapped approximately onto $3/4$ arc $|z|=R^3$. Combining this with the earlier observations about the boundary behavior of $\Phi$, conclude that 
the winding number of $\Phi$ about every point in its image is $1$.

**Endgame**

Recall  our ugly thing $\Omega$: it is not exactly the image of positive quadrant under $\Phi$, but is related by a linear transformation. 
Specifically, $w\mapsto -iw-2$ maps $\Omega$ onto the image of $\Phi$. Hence, 
$$z\mapsto \Phi^{-1}(-iz^2-2)\tag{1}$$
sends half-domain onto first quadrant. Note that the line $L$ is sent to the positive real half-axis. Reflecting along $L$,  we conclude that (1) is a map of the original region onto the right half-plane. Multiply by $i$.

---

This is not a reasonable exam problem, in my opinion.

Answer (score 1):

The function $f(z) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}(1-z)\sqrt{z+2}$ maps the right half plane conformally onto the portion of the plane to the left of $x^2-y^2=1$.

Its the composite of the $z^3-3z$, $\frac{1}{2}z+1$ and $\sqrt{z}$.

Comment: The equation asked for a map in the opposite direction, from hyperbola-bounded region to halfplane. It does not look like $f$ is easy to invert, although it's possible that the author of the question would accept an implicitly defined map.

Comment: Oh...good point.

Comment: I would like to understand better your method, which seems to be the one Ahlfors is indicating. I don't quite know what he means by "on one side" and "on the other side..."

Comment: The truth is I'm embarrassed to admit I don't have a method - just going off Ahlfors' hints. By "on one side" and the "other side" he's just using a figure of speech. Think "on one hand" and "the other hand". Look at the image of $g(z) = 2(z^2 -1)$ on the upper half of the region determined by the hyperbola, and the image of $h(w) = w^3 - 3w$ on the lower right quadrant: They're the same image (I think). Compose $g^{-1} \circ h$ and notice that the composition is analytic. That's all I got... ;)

Comment: When you say "the lower right quadrant", do you (and does Ahlfors) mean the entire quadrant, or just the part to the left of the hyperbola?

Comment: One more thing: Ahlfors attributes the mapping to Lindelof (one of his advisors). For me, it's a pretty hard problem.

Comment: Look at the image of $h$ on the union of the positive real axis and the positive imaginary axis. Look at the image of $g$ on the set $z < 1$ unioned with the part of the hyperbola above the real axis.